# Sharing Singleton logic between projects, with modifications for each project

Tags: java, android

I am developing two Android applications with similar -- but not identical -- logic, and I want to share code between them. Currently, I have a project for each application, and an additional project for shared classes. The shared-classes project is a library, and the application projects are linked to this library.

The problem I have is with a class that's responsible for getting data from the server and caching that data. The class is called DataSingleton. Fetching the data has some logic which is the same for both applications, and some which is different. My question is how to design the class to support this.

There are some limitations here:

1. The data Singleton should be a singleton, as implied by its name.
2. Some of the shared logic in the shared project uses the DataSingleton, so the DataSingleton must also be in the shared-classes project (otherwise I get a build error).
3. I don't want to put the application-specific logic in the shared project.

If this was C++, I would have 2 different classes name DataSingleton -- one in each application -- and then have the linker connect the correct class. Both classes could inherit from some common base class, to handle the code sharing for shared logic. Can I do something similar in Java?

If it helps, I can "initialize" the DataSingleton at the start of the application with some argument that will determine its behavior. I thought about passing a class to it, but then that class doesn't have access to the DataSingleton's private members.

What is the "right" way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about singleton. It is a class that does 3 thigs:
1. it has a business logic
2. it creates instance of itself
4. it holds this single instance and provides access to it.

You want to hold more than one implementations of your class. This means that you need interface and/or abstract base class and several concrete classes. But in this case the best  solution is to separate #1 from #2 and #3: create hierarchy of `DataFetcher`s (I am sorry, I changed your name `DataSingleton` because it does not describe the reality any more) and `DataFetcherAccessor`:

```
interface DataFetcher {}
class DataFetcher1 implements DataFetcher{}
class DataFetcher2 implements DataFetcher{}

class DataFetcherAccessor<A extends DataFetcher> {
    private static A accessor;

    public static void setImpl(Class<A> c) {
        accessor = c.newInstance();
    }

    public static A getAccessor() [
        return accessor;
    }
}
```

There are obviously a lot of other solutions. For example you can use [SPI](https://code.google.com/p/spi/) to locate available implementation of your interface. You can also scan your classpath yourself and discover available implementation of interface `DataFetcher` or use [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Strip the `DataSingleton` in the shared project of the parts that will need to change in the different projects, define it as an abstract class and change its name to `AbstractDataSingleton` or something like that, then just create 2 separate classes in each product called `DataSingleton` or whatever and make them extend the `AbstractDataSingleton` in the shared project.

Comment: I have some shared logic that uses DataSingleton. How will it know which class to use now?

Comment: You will have to explain more clearly what you mean by "shared logic". Assuming your applications don't interact with each other there will never be 2 `DataSingleton`s at any point, if ProjectA is run then the shared logic will use the extended ProjectA's `DataSingleton` if ProjectB is run then the shared logic will use the extended ProjectB's `DataSingleton`

Comment: If you have a need to run the shared project standalone (although you said it was only used as a library) you can create a `DataSingleton` next to your `AbstractDataSingleton` which extends it and contains the necessary data and can be used standalone only for the needs of the Shared project but will not be used by either ProjectA or ProjectB

Comment: Suppose I have a class in the shared project that needs to use the interface provided by DataSingleton. To get an instance of the singleton it should do something like DataSingleton.instance(). What you suggest is changing it to something like DataSingletonA.instance(). But then it's specific for app A...

Comment: Since the shared method requires the singleton you could add an argument to that method and pass it the `AbstractDataSingleton` based instance related to your project. For example if the method was `someSharedMethod()` before you can change it to `someSharedMethod(AbstractDataSingleton singleton)` and then when you need to invoke it from either ProjectA or ProjectB you simply invoke it like `someSharedMethod(DataSingleton.instance())`